# Set selected Radio Button from group using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, radio-group

Have this on the html side:

```
 <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" formControlName="title" maxlength="50"/>
 <div class="form-control radio">
 <input type="radio" class="m-r-5" value="2" name="rgLongTerm"> <label> all </label>
 <input type="radio" class="m-r-5" value="0" name="rgLongTerm"> <label> no </label>
 <input type="radio" class="m-r-5" value="1" name="rgLongTerm"> <label> yes </label>
 </div>
```

And I have the textbox with value set like this on the .ts side:

```
 form.controls.title.patchValue(filter.data);
```

(and that part works) where **filter.data** comes from the database

Now, I added this radio button group, and just like the textbox is getting filled with the patchvalue, I would like to select the one of 3 radio buttons, based on the value which is inside a **filter.data2** (can have value 0,1,2) for example.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you please make a stackblitz.

Comment: sure just add whatever you have developed(radio button section) in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` in your input should be `[value]=0` if your filter.data2 is a number. You’re also missing the `formControlName` in the `input`. An example should be like this:  `<input type="radio" class="m-r-5" formControlName=“rgLongTerm” [value]=2 name="rgLongTerm"> <label> all </label>`

Have you tried  `form.controls.rgLongTerm.patchValue(filter.data);`? Also you can also set a default value by doing this

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
   'rgLongTerm': new FormControl(filter.data2)
});
```

Comment: I added the [value] and the formControlName , then when form.controls.rgLongTerm.patchValue(filter.data) did not work, I added a parseInt, then it worked. Thank you !